# Get radio button's value from a form by PHP

Tags: craft3, form, php

I have been developing validations for my form.

It is possible to get text input's value like;

`$password = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('password');`

However, this function seems not to work for radio button fields. Could you tell me how to get radio button's value?

Comment: I found that getBodyParam function's param is the element's id. However, for radio button, the key must be name. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by myself;

```
$application = $event->sender->application;
```

Even for radio button's value, no suffix is necessary like `value`.